# Installing failover cluster after SQL installation

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, clustering

Will there be any issue if WSFC is installed after SQL is already installed for the purpose of configuring Always ON?
SQL Server version 2017 Enterprise
Windows version 2019 standard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always-on is an umbrella under which Microsoft regrouped a few high availability technologies.  Main ones are: Always-on Availability Groups and Always-on Failover cluster Instances.

If it's only for Always-On availability group (to which most peoples refer to when they say "always-on"), it's not a problem to install and configure the Windows cluster after SQL Server installation.

However, if you want to convert your standalone SQL Server instance to a Failover Cluster Instance (FCI), that's not possible in-place: you'll have to install a new SQL Server clustered instance and migrate your database from the standalone instance.

Comment: So, for Always-On availability group, I do not need windows cluster (Even in SQL 2017). Is that correct statement?

Comment: Well.. It depends.  If you want an availability group for high availablity and disaster recovery with all the features, Windows failover cluster is required.  If you just want a secondary read replica, you could look at read-scale availability group without Windows cluster.